# Select2 4.0.5 common errors in Django admin

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-4, django-2.1

(Disclaimer: this is a self-answered question)

I wanted to set up some [Select2](https://select2.org/) to my form fields while in a Django admin panel (specifically in the `change_list.html` template). So I added the neccesary scripts to the page (not the full version), but when it loads, I get this errors:

```
Select2: An instance of jQuery or a jQuery-compatible library was not found. Make
    sure that you are including jQuery before Select2 on your web page.
TypeError: a is undefined
TypeError: e is undefined
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

And when you search for one of those errors (well, not the first and last ones), the answers aren't on the same subject (normally it has to do with a bad `processResults` setup, or problems with Bootstrap) or in the [docs](https://select2.org/troubleshooting) neither.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps involved fixing it:

### Setting a var called `$`

This one is the first thing you think of when you see the last line (`TypeError: $ is not a function`), and all scripts normally use it (who doesn't uses `$` in their scripts?). But when you modify it, you still get these errors:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
TypeError: e is undefined
```

So, we have to go deeper...

### Setting a var called `jQuery`

This one can be a little hidden, as we have to dig into the `select2.js` script (you normally use the minified version, so only `$` is showed instead).

Looks like a var called `jQuery` is used sometimes, so you also have to set it up in your JS.

### How the fix should look like

Add this script before your Select2 scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // To prevent errors for Select2 JS
    var $ = django.jQuery;
    var jQuery = django.jQuery;
</script>
```